# Finding a special sequence related to primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $(g_{k})_{k≥1}$ be the sequence of primes gaps (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Lower_bounds). I am asking about the possibility of finding a real sequence $(x_{k})_{k≥1}$ with the following properties:

(1) $0<x_{k}<1$

(2) $g_{k}<1/x_{k}$ for all $k>0$. Here I understand that the inequality holds true for all finite primes.

(3) The sequence $x_{k}$ does not have a limit when $k$ goes to infinity.

If condition (2) leads to a contradiction, then we can replace it by the statement:

(2)': $g_{k}<1/x_{k}$ for infinitely many indices $k>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your updated question, the answer is yes, you can find a real sequence with those $3$ properties. You can choose any relatively small $\epsilon \gt 0$ and then set $x_k = \frac{1}{g_k + \epsilon}$. This obviously meets condition (1), as well as condition (2) as it's equivalent to $x_k \lt \frac{1}{g_k}$.

As for condition (3), note there is no upper limit on $g_k$ since, for example, for any $n \gt 1$, you have that $n! + 2$ to $n! + n$ are all composite. However, recently in $2013$, Yitang Zhang proved, e.g., as explained in [Bounded Gaps Between Primes](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2014/179-3/p07), there's an integer $\lt 7 \times 10^7$ for which there are an infinite number of prime gaps. This was later improved to $246$ (e.g., as stated in the last paragraph of the [Upper bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) section of Wikipedia's "Prime Gaps" article).

This combination of no upper limit on the prime gaps and that there are infinitely many prime gaps of less than or equal to $246$ shows the sequence of $(x_{k})_{k≥1}$ will jump between near $0$ and a value $\ge \frac{1}{246 + \epsilon}$ infinitely often and, thus, it does not have a limit.

Comment: But the Zhang's result is conditional. My idea is t use the  Robert Rankin result in the linked page, i.e., condition $(2)'$. But I am not able to do this.

Comment: @Helena Actually, a major reason everyone was so excited about Zhang's result is that it was *unconditional*, e.g., as the Wikipedia article says "... but Zhang Yitang's result *proves* that it is true for at least one (currently unknown) value of $k$ ...", with the emphasis mine.

Comment: But it was used the Elliott–Halberstam conjecture.

Comment: @Helena I believe you are confusing the possibility of reducing the bound down to $12$ or $6$ by using the Elliott-Halberstam conjecture. In particular, the [Research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitang_Zhang#Research) section of Wikipedia's "Yitang Zhang" article says, at the end, "... in fact $k \le 12$ and $k \le 6$ follow using current methods if the Elliott–Halberstam conjecture and its generalisation, respectively, hold." However, the $246$ limit doesn't depend on this. Also, shortly after Yitang, James Maynard used a *different* technique to show "$P(k)$ holds for some $k \le 600$".

Comment: It is Ok. But I am asking about the pôssibility of using  the Robert Rankin result in the linked page.

Comment: @Helena Your question only specifically said to use the prime gaps, without saying you only wanted to use certain ones, e.g., the ones satisfying the Robert Rankin result. Also, note it's not in the section you linked to (i.e., "Upper bounds") but, instead, it's in the next section (i.e., "Lower Bounds"). In addition, if you only want to use prime gaps which are more than a lower bound that goes to infinity, and if we're not allowed to use any other results, then one can't say for certain whether or not there's a limit. Are we allowed to use anything else?

Comment: Yes. We can use other results.